# error with define macro definition

Tags: c++

when i am using `#define` function,I observe something bizarre.
   In the below code if I gave `i` value as `'10'` from input `i` got the output as `132`. However if I declare `i=10` by commenting 10,12 and 13 lines then my output is `144`. can anyone explain me how this is happening? 
thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define Double(X) X*X 

int main()
{

 //int i=10;
 int i;

cout<<"Enter the i values:" <<endl;
cin>>i;

cout<<"Values is:"<<Double(++i)<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`Double(++i)` will expand to `++i * ++i`. In this expression, `i` is modified twice without an intervening [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), which is *undefined behavior*.

Read: [So, what's wrong with using macros?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#macro)

Comment: yes i understand it is ++i * ++i, but why the result is varied for both cases.I mean if i declare 'i=10' then my result is 132. Also, if i provide the 'i' value using cin the result is 144.

Comment: @user2413497 that is what we say [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)!

Answer (score 1):

What you have is undefined behaviour.

You `Double(++i)` is changed to `++i * ++i`, when you compile you code.

Answer (score -1):

Macro's have subtleties.
What your macro does is:
`Double(++i) -> ++i*++i`

in your case 11*12 or 12*11

Comment: yes i understand it is ++i * ++i, but why the result is varied for both cases.I mean if i declare 'i=10' then my result is 132. Also, if i provide the 'i' value using cin the result is 144