# Unary operation are sometimes suicidal.Mess up with C code

Tags: c, macros, pre-increment, unary-operator

Code in C language.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define PRODUCT(x) ( x * x * x)
int main()
{
  int i =5,k;
  k = PRODUCT( ++i );
  printf("i is :%d ",k);
  return 0;
}
```

My Question is why `i` is : `392`? According to me output should be `336`. (because `6 * 7 * 8 = 336`)

Am I really messed up here??

Comment: Because `++i * ++i * ++i` is undefined behaviour

Comment: [error with define macro definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038558/error-with-define-macro-definition/17038596#17038596)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You are Wrong..Please see Dayal rai comment below to see how it will be preprocessed.

Comment: @simonc Ok I got it..Thanks for help ,so it is duplicate.

Comment: @Level29Access my answer is perfectly correct over there, that is quit related to your answer. yes Dayal rai's answer it correct, you can vote & accept the answer

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Sorry I haven't visited the link..+1 for correcting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessed code will have

`( ++i * ++i * ++i)`

which have Lack of [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the two execution on same variable resulting [Undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).