# Behaviour of macros and increment operator in C

Tags: c

When I compile the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define CUBE(x) (x*x*x)

int main()
{
    int a, b=3;
    a = CUBE(b++);
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives **27 , 6**

But shouldn't the expression `a=b++*b++*b++;` be calculated as `a=3*4*5` and should give `60`?

Comment: Undefined behavior aside, the macro should be `#define CUBE(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))`

Comment: Read [error with define macro definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038558/error-with-define-macro-definition/17038596#17038596)

Answer (score 4):

Your expression causes undefined behaviour, so you could get *any* answer.  Trying to modify the same value more than twice between sequence points is bad news.